# python convert str to timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to convert time offsets formatted as `str` to `datetime.timedelta` objects, then plot the curve of observations versus time.

```
'5 days, 4:23:52.480000'  ;      17.647166
'5 days, 5:56:09.166000' ;        22.916071
'5 days, 8:21:40.261000'  ;      18.922329
'5 days, 9:53:18.070000'    ;    21.392157
'6 days, 0:07:54.487000'  ;      20.275597
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you show your efforts as SO is not a code writing service, please show what the desired plot looks like

Comment: This looks like you actually want `timedelta`, not `datetime`, correct?

Comment: _italic_  Yes exactly   @Paul

Answer (score 1):

There is no parser for timedeltas. So you have to build one yourself:

```
import re
delta = '5 days, 4:23:52.480000' 
days, hours, minutes, seconds = re.match('(?:(\d+) days, )?(\d+):(\d+):([.\d+]+)', delta).groups()
total_seconds = ((int(days or 0) * 24 + int(hours)) * 60 + int(minutes)) * 60 + float(seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks, it’s useful for me, but in the regexp you need to consider the case `1 day` without plural s, so this part in the regexp must be `(\d+) days?` instead of `(\d+) days`, and the string should be prefixed with `r`, the complete line becomes then 
```python
days, hours, minutes, seconds = re.match(r'(?:(\d+) days?, )?(\d+):(\d+):([.\d+]+)', event.duration_str).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of anything that parses text into `timedelta`, the format you have specified is understood by the [`pandas.Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) constructor, so if you want, you can use that to construct your timedeltas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [['5 days, 4:23:52.480000', 17.647166],
     ['5 days, 5:56:09.166000', 22.916071],
     ['5 days, 8:21:40.261000', 18.922329],
     ['5 days, 9:53:18.070000', 21.392157],
     ['6 days, 0:07:54.487000', 20.275597]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['TimeOffset', 'Value'])

df['TimeOffset'] = df['TimeOffset'].apply(pd.Timedelta)

plt.plot(df['TimeOffset'], df['Value'])
plt.show()
```

People who know pandas better, feel free to edit this answer (and remove this message) - I feel like the way I constructed the `pd.Timedelta` column may be non-idiomatic.